# Prove that $(E): x² - 2px + q = 0 $ if and only if $p² - q \in B \subset \mathbb{Z_{11}} $, and determine $B$.

Tags: arithmetic

It is clear that: $x² - 2px + q = (x-p)² - p²+q = 0 $

The equation $(E)$ becomes: $ (x - p)² = p² - q $

Also, we have the equation $x²=a$ admits solutions if and only if $a = 0,1, 4, 9$ (Am I correct?)

Which means $(E)$ admits solutions only if $p²-q \in \{0, 1, 4, 9\} $ (Am I correct?)

The next question was to solve the equation $ x^4+3x²+4 = O $ in $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$.

$x^4+3x²+4 = 0 \iff (x²-2)² = -x² - 3 $

I am unable to proceed to solve this because $ x $ is in both sides. How can I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: $p^2-q$ must be one of $0,1,3,4,5,9$.

Comment: @Bernard Because $3 \equiv 25 [11] $ and $5 \equiv 16 [11] $? With $25 = 5²$ and $16 = 4² $.

Comment: Yes. Just compute all squares in $\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z$  (to speed up the calculations, you can write its elements as $0,\pm1,\dots,\pm5$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Do as for all biquadratic equations: set $y=x^2$, and solve for $\;y^2+3y+4=0$ first. Then check whether the found roots are squares.

*Some details:

The discriminant is $\;\Delta=9-16=-7=4=(\pm2)^2$. On the other hand, $2^{-1}=6$, so 
$$y=\frac{-3\pm 2}2=\begin{cases}-5\cdot 6=3,\\-1\cdot 6=5.\end{cases}$$

Comment: $y² + 3y + 4 = 0 $ doesn't have roots because $ \Delta = - 7 < 0 $. The set of solutions is the empty set. Correct?

Comment: Negative numbers are meaningless in a finite field. Furthermore, $-7=4$.

Comment: $ y² + 3y + 4 = 0 \iff (y + 1)^² = y + 3 $. And from the previous question
 $y +3$ must be one of $0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 9$. 

If for example, $ y + 3 = 0 $, we'll have $ y + 1 = 0 $. 

I am confused. Could you please explain to me? Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the resolution formulae? $4$ has two  square roots, and you only have to compute the inverse of $2$.

Comment: What do you mean by the resolution formulae?

Comment: Didn't you learn formulae for quadratic equations in high-school?

Comment: English is not my primary langague, sorry. 

$\Delta = 4 = 2² = (-2)² $, we will have: $y_1 = - \frac{5}{2}$ and $y_{2} = -1$

$ - 1 = 10 $ which cannot be written as $ 10 = x² $. 

The equation doesn't have a solution. Is it correct? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's an error: $-1$ is not a root, and $5/2$ has to be simplified. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: So we will have $x² = 3 = 5²$ and $x² = 5 = 4²$, the set of solutions is $ \{4,5 \}$. Correct? Thank you so very much for your help sir.

Comment: It's exactly that.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir!